# How would I fill the component (Vuetify component) type dynamically in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, vuetify.js

My actual code:

```
    <component :is="type === 'v-text-field'">
      <v-text-field v-bind="props" />
    </component>
    <component :is="type === 'v-autocomplete'">
      <v-autocomplete v-bind="props" />
    </component>
```

I would like to be more cleaner, like this:

```
<:type v-bind="props" />
```

I know my code above is wrong, but I would like to replace that type with a vuetify component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Vue.js [dynamic components documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components), the special `is` attribute can container either:

- the name string of a registered component, OR
- the actual imported component object

But you are providing it with a boolean instead.

As far as I understand, this line should be enough:

```html
<component :is="type" v-bind="props">
```

Comment: I just noticed I'm being redundant, because I'm trying to clean my code, creating more code. lol...